# Set content width to automatically be to equal width

Tags: css, angularjs, responsive-design

The question title could be more clear, but given some text, if the browser width lets it fit on one line, then I want it to be centered, otherwise, I don't want just one word wrapping to the next line, how do I make sure that it break the lines to be about equal lengths? If there's a CSS only way that's be best, otherwise, I'd like to do it in Angular 2...

i.e:

```
Desktop:
[Screen Edge]...."Some interesting text is here"....[Screen Edge]

Phone:
[Screen Edge]....."Some interesting"......[Screen Edge]
[Screen Edge]......."text is here"........[Screen Edge]

NOT 
Phone:
[Screen Edge]."Some interesting text is"..[Screen Edge]
[Screen Edge]..........."here"............[Screen Edge]
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1:

use `flexbox`:

with `flex-wrap: wrap;` and wrap your text with `div` so it will break at the point you want when you need to wrap.

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10vh 15vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <span>Some interesting text is here&nbsp;</span><span>Some interesting text is here&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

## Option 2:

use `text-align: center;` to center text

use `margin: 5px 80px;` to create basic margin

use `&nbsp;` non-breaking space to make sure your text does not break.
(or you can wrap the text with span with a css rule set `white-space: nowrap`)

```css
.centered {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.centered > div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10vh 15vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered"><div>Some&nbsp;interesting text&nbsp;is&nbsp;here Some&nbsp;interesting text&nbsp;is&nbsp;here</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I hope it helps. You must set your container to text-align: center to center the texts. If you want it fluid, you set its width to 100%. You may also add padding so when you switch to mobile, it will not looked populated.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
body > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
body > div > div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 40px;
}
.web {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
}
.mobile {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="web">
      <div class="container">
        <span>Some interesting text here</span>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile">
    <div class="container">
        <span>Some interesting text here</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```